# Issues with Open Ai vision into react native application due to url error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a react native application. I want this application to allow the user to upload an image. Once the image was selected and uploaded, it is published to firebase and grabs a public downloadable link.

I then want to pass this link of the downloadable image to Open Ai's vision api. Once it is passed to OpenAi, I want it to scan the image and answer a question about the image.

I have tried everything but I am not sure what is going on.

This is the code I have:

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import {OPEN_AI_API_KEY} from '../../Utils/Authentication';
import {uploadNewImage} from '../../Utils/Firebase';

const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: OPEN_AI_API_KEY});
console.log(openai);

...

const performOCR = () => {
    const fileName = 'receipt-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000 + 1);
    uploadNewImage(preprocessedImage, fileName)
      .then(downloadableUrl => {
        console.log('received downloadable url');
        if (downloadableUrl) {
          console.log(downloadableUrl);
          scanImage(downloadableUrl);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

async function scanImage(downloadableUrl: string) {
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-4-vision-preview',
      messages: [
        {
          role: 'user',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text',
              text: 'Scan the image of the receipt and extract the business information. Then itemize all of the items that were ordered?',
            },
            {
              type: 'image_url',
              image_url: {
                url: downloadableUrl,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
    console.log(response.choices[0]);
  }
```

So at some point of the process it keeps throwing an error about the failure of my url. I have looked online and asked chat gpt for help and nothing.

Here is the full error tract:

```
 LOG  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ioweyou-9d178.appspot.com/o/ProfilePictures%2Freceipt-27195586?alt=media&token=a4320778-e64e-4325-a236-460bb7d9e3c1
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: 404 Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions/)
Error: 404 Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions/)
    at construct (native)
    at Wrapper (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:26976:64)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219299:406)
    at apply (native)
    at OpenAIError (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219310:26)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219299:406)
    at call (native)
    at APIError (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219321:27)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219299:406)
    at apply (native)
    at NotFoundError (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219477:29)
    at generate (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:219365:35)
    at makeStatusError (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:217534:79)
    at ?anon_0_ (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:217592:43)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:28227:26)
    at _next (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:28246:29)
    at tryCallOne (/private/var/folders/yw/6bx918xn4671rggfcdxz7fph0000gn/T/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)
    at anonymous (/private/var/folders/yw/6bx918xn4671rggfcdxz7fph0000gn/T/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:34858:26)
    at _callTimer (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:34737:17)
    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:34782:17)
    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:34988:44)
    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:3623:46)
    at anonymous (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:3397:45)
    at __guard (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:3596:15)
    at flushedQueue (http://192.168.86.62:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:3396:21)
```